# Como implementar um "scroll hijacking"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho notado em diversas páginas modernas um comportamento de scroll que vai até determinada parte de interesse do conteúdo, pesquisando, descobri que esse tipo de comportamento é denominado "hijacking". O termo "hijacking" literalmente traduzido significa "sequestro". Possivelmente tenha alguma ligação com o fato de que nestas páginas o scroll definitivamente some e apresenta esse novo comportamento. Vi também que existem problemas de compatibilidade com este "efeito".

Tentando reproduzir esse comportamento, imaginei trabalhar com o [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), quando a posição do `scroll` estivesse sobre uma `section` usaria o `.animate` passando a posição do `scrollTop`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Por fim, gostaria de saber como implementar algo parecido, ou se alguém já possui algo pronto e queira compartilhar, agradeço.

Segue um exemplo do hijacking scroll: [codyhouse - hijacking](https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/fixed-hijacking.html), basta habilitar a opção hijacking.

Comment: Você gostaria de entender como funciona ou exemplos funcionais?

Comment: @Randrade Se possível os dois, mas com um exemplo funcional acredito que eu já entenda o funcionamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos entender melhor o que significa **Hijacking Scroll**.

A tradução literal do termo ([pelo Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/Hijacking%20Scroll)) é "sequestro de rolagem", o que define perfeitamente o que é.

O sequestro de rolagem é quando você controla a barra de rolagem do usuário, ou seja, o usuário não tem controle da ação que será realizada ao rolar o `scroll`, e você define isso em seu código.

Essa é uma atitude "drástica" e existe algumas indagações se seu [uso realmente é bom](http://trentwalton.com/2013/10/23/scroll-hijacking/) ou que [podem trazer problemas, especialmente para dispositivos mobiles.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53890)

Agora que sabemos o que é, vamos aos exemplos:

Você pode fazer isso somente com javascript (jQuery) e "sequestrar" o uso do *wheel* do mouse.

Veja o exemplo abaixo [retirado desta pergunta.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41639433/4843158)

```js
// I need to make this dynamic
var currentSection = $('#section1');
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
  var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
  if (delta > 0 && currentSection.next().length > 0) {
    currentSection = currentSection.next();
    scrollTo(currentSection);
  } else if (delta < 0 && currentSection.prev().length > 0) {
    currentSection = currentSection.prev();
    scrollTo(currentSection);
  }

  function scrollTo(el) {
    realoffSet = el.offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: realoffSet
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="full"></div>
<div id="section2" class="full"></div>
<div id="section3" class="full"></div>
```

Esse é um exemplo simples do seu uso. No exemplo que você mencionou, ainda possui âncoras para as `sections`, mas isso é uma funcionalidade a mais.

O exemplo que você postou está utilizando o [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/), conforme muito bem mostrado na [resposta o @Leon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210643/20615).

Outro exemplo de plugin para fazer isso é o [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js), que faz o que você deseja além de outros efeitos.

Veja o exemplo de sua utilização abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    scrollingSpeed: 1000
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.intro p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#menu li.active {
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}

#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#menu li.active a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#menu li a,
#menu li.active a {
  padding: 9px 18px;
  display: block;
}

#menu li.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 70;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#demosMenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section " id="section0">
    <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section active" id="section1">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>Create Sliders</h1>
        <p>Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="imgs/1.png" alt="simple" />
        <h1>Simple</h1>
        <p>Easy to use. Configurable and customizable.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>Cool</h1>
        <p>It just looks cool. Impress everybody with a simple and modern web design!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="imgs/3.png" alt="Compatible" />
        <h1>Compatible</h1>
        <p>Working in modern and old browsers too! IE 8 users don't have the fault of using that horrible browser! Lets give them a chance to see your site in a proper way!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Working On Tablets</h1>
      <p>
        Designed to fit to different screen sizes as well as tablet and mobile devices.
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Caso queira saber um pouco mais sobre o assunto, eu achei [este artigo](https://envato.com/blog/scroll-hijacking/) bem interessante e também possui alguns argumentos sobre o seu uso.

Comment: "Reset CSS" em exemplos específicos me parece um problema, o exemplo tá otimo, mas se o cara não entender muito de CSS e copiar isto pode conflitar com alguma outra coisa, me permite remover o CSS desnecessário?

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente o primeiro exemplo que eu procurava, muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, vou avaliar através do artigo se convém utilizar o hijacking scroll.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Na verdade eu apenas utilizei o css que o fullPage possui em [sua live](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/examples.css). Mas, realmente, várias coisas não são necessárias para o seu funcionamento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Removi o css não utilizável. Mas, se achar que seja necessário mais alguma alteração, sinta-se à vontade para realizar.

Comment: Nada, tá otimo assim

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei um fiddle com a utilização desse Scroll Hijacking pela Velocity utilizado no seu exemplo e você pode conferir lá o seu funcionamento. Nesse caso é tudo baseado no Velocity.js, que é um plugin que irá fazer toda a animação para você utilizando apenas alguns comandos simples.

Você pode verificar que no `<body>` há a opção de ligar/desligar o scroll hijacking.

Segue o link: [Velocity - Scroll Hijacking](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/xnjnq51L/)

**Detalhe Importante:** Ele não tem funcionamento Mobile

Comment: E não é melhor manter o plugin separado e usar o plugin mesmo, assim se houver correções de bugs o usuário do script consegue mante-lo, ao invés de copiar o source do Velocity todo. Versionamento existe para isto, melhorias e correções, não concorda? Você mesmo pode criar um fork do [Velocity](http://velocityjs.org/) e assim criar e distribuir teu proprio plugin, até mesmo posteriormente compartilhar via CDN.

Comment: Concordo. Estou apenas constando que aqui usei o Velocity do exemplo dado pelo OP, embora não seja a única forma de fazer isto. Eu, pessoalmente, prefiro evitar o uso de plugins.

Comment: o velocity é customizavel, penso eu que poderia ajustar o registro de eventos e até simplificar e ainda atingir o mesmo efeito. O problema é se o que fez tiver alguma falha, não é questão de plugins é questão de versionamento, tem plugin bom, tem plugin ruim, a diferença é que coisas "versionadas" e mantidas por grupos e open-source tem mais garantias de não falhar ou até melhorar algo que já é considerado bom.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim. Pelo pouco que vi do Velocity, ele dá várias formas diferentes de transição, velocidade, e a possibilidade de ligar ou desligar o Hijack. Já na questão do versionamento, achei curioso que nada funcionou com a versão mais atual do Velocity. Para fazer com que o exemplo funcionasse, utilizei uma versão mais antiga dele. Agora, apenas na minha opinião, se for a única forma de fazer algo, eu vou usar plugins, mas se não, eu sempre prefiro não utilizar, para que eu não dependa de nada.

Comment: Para você somente usar é um argumento valido, para distribuição eu já não acho, a não ser que vc ensine a criar um explicando cada detalhe. Dizer *"eu prefiro não usar plugins, mas copio o source deles"* é quase uma redundância, eu não estou te criticando, só estou tentando lhe mostrar as vantagens e desvantagens que eu pessoalmente acredito.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas eu não copiei o source. Eu peguei todos os possíveis por CDN. O único que usei ali foi do Main.js porque não achei em CDN, acredito que seja próprio e eu não tenho como hospedar ele. O exemplo tem 4 js importados.

Comment: Copiar não é na "integra", é copiar parcialmente, se basear, etc. Mas as vantagens e desvantagens eu lhe apresentei, como eu disse pra uso pessoal parece uma boa pra compartilhar é que complica. Sei que pareço chato, mas de uma lida boa sobre versionamento, com o tempo talvez comece a perceber (ou não), de qualquer forma são dicas e só ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Relaxa. Não estou te achando chato. Pra mim, todo novo conhecimento é válido.. Só não tenho certeza se ambos estamos nos entendendo aqui. Hahaha... Eu tenho noções de plugins e versões. Já usei muito plugin. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Criei um exemplo simples e prático:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('li').click(function(){
    switch(jQuery(this).text().trim()){
       case 'Vermelho':
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        break;
        case 'Verde':
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 500
        }, 500);
        break;
        case 'Azul':
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 1000
        }, 500);
        break;
      }
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #CCC;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #CCC:
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Vermelho</li>
  <li>Verde</li>
  <li>Azul</li>
</ul>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```